# Redirecting user after login when using the ip_login module

Tags: 6, redirection

I'm trying to show a different frontpage to users of a specific role, using the [Front Page module](http://drupal.org/project/front) (version 6.x-2.0-rc1) in alias mode. This works fine for users that are already logged in, but the problematic point now is that I'm also using the [IP Login module](http://drupal.org/project/ip_login) (version 6.x-1.2) to log in certain users based on their IP address. This login seems to work differently from the usual login via the `/user` page.

Those users that are logged in via IP, they first get the normal frontpage that anonymous users get, they are not redirected automatically to the special frontpage I defined using the Frontpage module. If they reload the frontpage they are already logged in now and they see the special frontpage as intended.

The usual ways of using the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/node/298506) or the [Login Redirect module](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) to redirect the users after they login just don't work, the users are not getting redirected when they are logged in via IP address.

Any ideas on how I could work around this problem, so that users logged in via IP see the special, redirected frontpage directly after openening the page?

Comment: are you using the latest dev (2.x) version?

Comment: I'm using version 6.x-2.0-rc1 of the Front Page module, I assume that was the module you're referring to.

Comment: I asking about the IP Login Module. Oh! you have already mentioned that you are using 6.x-1.2, try the latest dev version that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by charan in a comment, this works in version 6.x-2.0-rc1 of the IP Login module.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when using the Secure Pages module. I tried the [Login redirect](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) module,  without success; I have finally found the [Login/Logout Destinations](http://drupal.org/project/loginlogout) module which worked perfectly (and still does).

> This module adds the destination back to the current page with JavaScript and checks to make sure the user has access before trying to have the user stay there on logout.